# Pole zero cancellation amplifier circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, pole-zeroplot, pole-compensation

I've built the circuit which looks like this:

[image]

At the input comes pulses from 30 volts biased photodiode.
After adding parallel 4.7 nF and 10kΩ for pole zero cancellation everything works fine, in AC oscilloscope mode pulses are nice shaped dropping to zero volt line, but when I switch oscilloscope to DC mode, I have added constant 5 volts.

How to correct this?

Do I have to add resistor R3 like in Fig.4?

[image]

Comment: What is the input? It is DC coupled and you have a bias at the input if you just have a resistor or photodiode so you will get a DC bias at the output.

Comment: What's the input offset on the first amp? With the huge gain even a tiny offset will become large by the output. You could add a trimmer to the noninverting input of the second amp to adjust the DC level.

Comment: There must be something I'm missing: you're talking about pulses as input, but also about pole-zero cancellation? Would you mind providing the connection between these two? Or maybe it's a language barrier? (I know I'm guilty of this)

Comment: Is it always 5V, or does it vary with the input?

Comment: @Aaron Input pulses appear on the 5V edge.